# little help on contact form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contact-form

I need some little help with my contact form. I'm building my website on dreamweaver and i have no server yet, i just need you to tell me what else is missing in my code for my contact form to work. 
2- i also need the "message sent" to appear below the message, because my site is a parallax one-pager. i dont want to make people leave my page.I have no clue where to put my e-mail address :(

```js
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit-form').click(function(e){
  
   e.preventDefault();
            var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            var Nome  = $('#form_name').val(),
    Email  = $('#form_email').val(),
    Assunto  = $('#form_subject').val(),
    Mensagem  = $('#form_message').val(),
    data_html,
    success = $('#success');
    
      if(name == "")
                $('#form_name').val('Please enter your name.');
    
   if(subject == "")
                $('#form_subject').val('Please enter your name.');

            if(email == ""){
                $('#form_email').val('Digite um e-mail válido.');
            }else if(reg.test(email) == false){
                $('#form_email').val('E-mail inválido.');
            }
   
            if(message == "")
                $('#form_message').val('Digite sua mensagem.');

            if(message != "" && name != "" && reg.test(email) != false) {
             data_html = "name=" + name + "&email="+ email + "&message=" + message + "&subject="+ subject;

                //alert(data_html);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'contact_form.php',
                    data: data_html,
                    success: function(msg){
      
      if (msg == 'sent'){
                         success.html('<div class="alert alert-success">Mensagem enviada!</div>')  ;
                            $('#form_name').val('');
       $('#form_email').val('');
       $('#form_message').val('');
                        }else{
                            success.html('<div class="alert alert-error">Message <strong>not</strong> sent! Please Try Again!</div>')  ; 
                        }
                    }
                });
    
            }
            return false;
        });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
textarea {
 height:167px;
 padding:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px; 
 overflow:auto;
}
 
.formSecWrap {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.formSecWrap2 {
 margin-right: 0px;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], textarea, select {
    background: #222222;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    width: 370px;
 font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
}
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px #fff;
}

.formWrap label{
 margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}
.formWrap input[type="submit"]{
 margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
 float: right;
}

a.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
 background: #7b133c; 
 border: none;
 padding: 4px 12px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
 line-height: 21px;
}
a.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover {
 color: #222;
 background: #ddd;  
}
```

```html
           <div id="contact_form">
                <div class="two-thirds column marginTop formWrap">
                    <form action="#" method="post" class="contactForm">
                        <div class="formSecWrap">
                            <label for="form_name">Nome</label>
                                <input type="text" id="form_name" name="form_name" value="" />
           
                            <label for="form_email">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="form_email" id="form_email" value="" />
                      
                            <label for="form_subject">Assunto</label>
                                <input type="text" name="form_subject" id="form_subject" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="formSecWrap formSecWrap2">
                            <label for="form_message">Mensagem</label>
                                <textarea class="textarea" name="form_message" id="form_message"></textarea>
                        
                                <input class="button" id="submit-form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="sucess"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
        
     </div>
```

Comment: There is an url there for the file `contact_form.php`. What is in there? There should be the email address.

Comment: @Claudiu, yes, i used the .php... but i am afraid it will take me another page? no?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have several issues.

But first, you don't have a server, but use an ajax to url: 'contact_form.php'.

That we'll never work in dreamweaver unless you configure a local server.

Sending mail with just javascript, no php, is problematic in many ways.

So, in order to make some progress, setup a proper local environment (like xampp maybe, or dreamweaver with local server) and test your mail form there where you can debug eventual javascript and php errors.

Comment: alright! My website is on! the contact form isnt working :) http://teste.paulorfloriano.com.br/